# Use Cortana to launch a specific web page

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Using Google Now on Android it's possible to say "Go to stackexchange.com" and it will successfully launch stackexchange.com in Chrome (or another browser you have installed).

I'm looking to duplicate that functionality using Cortana.

I'm not sure if it's possible at all, or if I just need to use certain key words.

I've tried "Navigate to stackexchange.com", but that actually pulls up the GPS navigator and tries to map my way to stackexchange.com

Using "Go to stackexchange.com" opens up a Bing search for "Go to stackexchange.com"

Is there any way to use Cortana voice commands to launch a specific web page?

Comment: As you stated, you wish to use voice commands to open a webpage. A friendly note that typing the URL into search/Cortana will open that webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. It seems Cortana can't open a specified website. I have switched to Braina and it works great. It can even learn and you can teach it custom commands. Check out the image here: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7EPwy_vm0-c/Vb4AJcujnPI/AAAAAAAABO8/CIBecmd-xAw/s1600/superuser.PNG

Check out this article which mentions 101 benefits of Braina over Cortana : http://www.brainasoft.com/braina/cortana-vs-braina.html